# How to get equal width charts - Apex Charts

Tags: javascript, css, apexcharts

I have two different graphs that I need to make. A simple bar graph, one with and one without labels on the xaxis. The design calls for this to be equal width, and no padding/margin on either side. As in it needs to line up with other objects.

The one chart uses the

```
sparkline: {
 enabled: true
},
```

option. The one with the labels gets the wrong width because of the labels. I have tried with css, but using [magic numbers](https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/) isn't smart because the values of the labels can change based on values, and thus the width.

Code for both:

https://codepen.io/cibgraphics/pen/JjZaxGB

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0qJ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just found a quite experimental solution to solve this problem. It is not very clean, but it is interesting to share...

The idea is to play with the `viewBox` attribute of your second `svg` element. It is documented here: [viewBox - SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

I also use the `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()` method.

> The `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()` method allows us to determine the coordinates of the smallest rectangle in which the object fits.

[SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

When the page loads, we can set the `viewBox` using the coordinates returned by `SVGGraphicsElement.getBBox()`. It works, but if you resize the window, another `svg` element is created and replace the current one. Thus, the `viewBox` is lost.

So the idea is now to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes in the DOM. Here we observe `#barChart2` because we are interested in one of its children (which is the `svg` element). When a change is detected, the custom `noPadding()` function is called.

Here is the code:

```js
function noPadding() {
  let svg = document.querySelector('#barChart2 svg'),
      {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();

  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${x} ${y} ${width} ${height}`);
}

let node = document.querySelector('#barChart2'),
    config = { childList: true },
    observer = new MutationObserver(() => noPadding());

observer.observe(node, config);
noPadding();
```

If I put the above code in what you did, we get this:

```js
var barChartOptions = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Actual',
    data: [{
        x: '2011',
        y: 12,
      },
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '22px',
    sparkline: {
      enabled: true
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true,
      borderRadius: 10,
      barHeight: '100%',
      colors: {
         backgroundBarColors: ['#E7E7E6'],
         backgroundBarRadius: '11px',
      }
    },
  },
  colors: ['#3CDBC0'],
  tooltip: {
    custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
      return (
        '<div class="arrow_box">' +
        "<span>" +
        series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>"
      );
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#barChart1"), barChartOptions);
chart.render();




var barChartOptions2 = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Actual',
    data: [{
        x: '2011',
        y: 10,
      },
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '90px',
    toolbar: {
      show: false
    },
  },
  grid: {
    show: false,
    padding: {
      right: 0,
      left: 0
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: false,
  },
  xaxis: {
    axisTicks: {
      color: '#000',
    },
  },
  dataLabels: {
   enabled: false,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true,
      borderRadius: 10,
      columnWidth: '100%',
      barHeight: '100%',
      colors: {
         backgroundBarColors: ['#E7E7E6'],
          backgroundBarRadius: '11px',
      },
    },
  },
  colors: ['#3CDBC0'],
  legend: {
    show: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
      return (
        '<div class="arrow_box">' +
        "<span>" +
        series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>"
      );
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#barChart2"), barChartOptions2);
chart.render();

// ==================================================

function noPadding() {
  let svg = document.querySelector('#barChart2 svg'),
      {x, y, width, height} = svg.getBBox();

  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${x} ${y} ${width} ${height}`);
}

let node = document.querySelector('#barChart2'),
    config = { childList: true },
    observer = new MutationObserver(() => noPadding());

observer.observe(node, config);
noPadding();
```

```css
.barChart {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.apexcharts-tooltip {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3.15331px 15.778px rgba(0, 45, 93, 0.2));
}

.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 10px;
  // margin-top: -10px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 13px;
  // margin-top: -13px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.barChart .apexcharts-tooltip {
  color: #000;
  transform: translateX(10px) translateY(10px);
  overflow: visible !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.barChart .apexcharts-tooltip span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="barChart1" class="barChart"></div>
<div id="barChart2" class="barChart"></div>
```